# how to switch states from input on game object

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a little project using Phaser 3 and I've run into a problem. I have two sprites that are interactable, and I want it to change the player state depending on which is pressed. The items don't move, I think of them as button that are set in another scene that is being launched.

So far my attempts have yielded only more questions about the logic.

```js
export let ToolSelectScene = new Phaser.Class({
  Extends: Phaser.Scene,
  initialize: function (config) {
    Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'ToolSelectScene' })
  },
  init: () => {
    console.log('tool select scene initialized')
  },
  preload: function () {
    this.load.multiatlas('items', 'assets/items.json', 'assets')
  },
  create: function () {
    this.gameScene = this.scene.get('GameScene')
    this.player = this.gameScene.players.getChildren()[0]

    this.weaponSlot1 = this.add
      .sprite(120, 37, 'items', 'swordsprite.png')
      .setInteractive()
    this.weaponSlot2 = this.add
      .sprite(150, 37, 'items', 'firesprite.png')
      .setInteractive()

    this.input.on('gameobjectdown', (pointer, object) => {
      console.log(object.frame.name)
      if (object.frame.name == 'swordsprite.png') {
        this.player.playerStateMachine.transition('useSword', object)
      }
      if (object.frame.name == 'firesprite.png') {
        console.log('use fire')
        this.player.playerStateMachine.transition('useFire', object)
      }
    })
  },
  update: function () {},
})
```

So when I run the code, the state changes but then something funny happens, the first state continues to be active while the second state has started. I've implemented a state machine, originally had written it like this but all in state code, and using the rexUI plugins.

I have state machines for each entity, which handles all the animation and input. I also tried using a switch, but since I'm using the same wrong logic it also didn't work.

How can I get this work properly?

If anyone has any advice on how to do this or any critiques and hints, I'd very much appreciate it. :)

edit: Oh I got it to work. I just turned off the event gameobjectdown as it changes state.

```js
this.toolSelectScene = scene.scene.get('ToolSelectScene')
this.toolSelectScene.input.on('gameobjectdown', (pointer, object) => {
  if (object.frame.name == 'swordsprite.png') {
    scene.input.off('gameobjectdown')
    this.stateMachine.transition('useSword')
  }
  if (object.frame.name == 'firesprite.png') {
    scene.input.off('gameobjectdown')
    this.stateMachine.transition('useFire')
  }
})
```

Comment: Ohh I got it to work. I had to turn off the gameobjectdown event as I change states.